# Limit Transfer Speed on Windows 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, networking

I have a Windows 2008 server that needs to have the network card traffic capped at 1 or 2 megabits.  Does anyone know if this can be accomplished by the Network card settings, registry trickery, or open-source/freeware applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be configured through GPO by applying a throttle rate to all source IP addresses associated to the card. See http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=59030735-8fde-47c7-aa96-d4108f779f20&displaylang=en for a detailed explanation.

Comment: This is an excellent read.

Answer (score 4):

Ummm, why would you want to restrict the network traffic? This type of setting I believe would have to be done at the switch level. If not what you can do is set your NIC to 10 Mbps half/full if you want to do that sort of thing on the server-side.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons to want to prevent something from hogging all of the available bandwidth. In one case, someone's roommate was using 95% of the bandwidth all day long and the router owner wanted to cap him. In my case, I need to do application testing as if I were a user with slow internet to find some bugs that only occur on slow connections.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it at the user level through group policy -> Network -> Limit Reservable Bandwidth and tuning it up to X% [10mbs would yield 80% reserved, 100mbps would be 98%]. However, this is only per user, if you have a system that runs all of it's apps as something besides administrator, YMMV.

Generally, however, this is easier to do through your switch and traffic shaping tools. Or if you really just need a speed reduction, kick the port into half-duplex.

Comment: This has just saved me no end of trouble. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you want a very flexible system, you might want to see if a VTun-like system for the TUN/TAP driver (which is available for Windows) exists for Win32 systems - but beware, messing with the TUN/TAP devices can be, well, messy.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [NetLimiter](http://www.netlimiter.com/):

> NetLimiter is an ultimate internet
>   traffic control and monitoring tool
>   designed for Windows. You can use
>   NetLimiter to set download/upload
>   transfer rate limits for applications
>   or even single connection and monitor
>   their internet traffic.

Comment: I did check out netlimiter, however, the latest version would bluescreen the server once turned on.

Answer (score 1):

Vista/Server2008 does have a network throttling mechanism included that is used when there is multimedia playing on the computer. It's a registry setting.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948066

If you can't throttle at the driver/switch level, you can probably utilize this as a workaround.

Comment: I will also look into this.